# mysql - satisfy composite primary key while using 'insert into xxx select'

Tags: mysql

I am importing data to a table structured: content_id|user_id|count - all integers all comprise the composite primary key

The table I want to select it from is structured: content_id|user_id

For reasons quite specific to my use case, I will need to fire quite a lot of data into this regularly enough to want a pure MySQL solution

```
insert into new_db.table
select content_id,user_id,xxx from old_db.table
```

I want each row to go in with xxx set to 0, unless this would create a duplicate key, in which case I wish to increment the number, for the current user_id/content_id combination

Not being a MySQL expert, I tried a few options like trying to populate xxx by selecting from the target table during insert, with no luck. Also tried using ON DUPLICATE KEY to increment counters instead of the usual UPDATE. But it all seemed a bit daft so I thought I would come here!

Any ideas anyone? I have a backup option of wrapping this in PHP, but it would drastically raise the overall running time of the script in which this would be the only non-pure MySQL part

Any help really appreciated. thanks in advance!

--edit

this may sound really awful in principle. but id settle for a way to do it in an update after entering random numbers (i have sent in random numbers to allow me to continue other work at the moment) - and this is a purely dev setup

--edit again

```
12|234
51|45
51|45
51|45
23|67
```

would ideally insert

```
12|234|0
51|45|0
51|45|1
51|45|2
23|67|0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_db.table (content_id, user_id, cnt)
SELECT old.content_id, old.user_id, COUNT(old.*) - 1 FROM old_db.table old
GROUP BY old.content_id, old.user_id
```

this would be the way I would go, so if 1 entry it would put 0 on cnt, for more it would just put 1-2-3 etc.

**Edit:**

Your correct answer would be somewhat complicated but I tested it and it works:

```
INSERT INTO newtable(user_id,content_id,cnt) 
SELECT o1.user_id, o1.content_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(@rownum, 0) = 0 
        THEN @rownum:=c-1
        ELSE @rownum:=@rownum-1
    END as cnt
FROM 
(SELECT user_id, content_id, COUNT(*) as c FROM oldtable
GROUP BY user_id, content_id ) as grpd 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT oldtable.* FROM oldtable) o1 ON 
(o1.user_id = grpd.user_id AND o1.content_id = grpd.content_id)
;
```

Comment: thanks. i just tried this on a small sample of data and it seems to be removing the duplicates, then offering a count of how many there `_were_` as opposed to keeping them and enumerating them from zero. not sure if i explained correctly, but i want all old data to go in - the use of the column named count is unhelpful i know - i didnt chose the destination structure ;o)

Comment: can you please give a small data sample, for what you need in question, since I think its kinda unclear at the moment.

Comment: sure thing. see the original question, ive added it up there. 
does that help? sorry for being unclear, and thanks for taking a look!

Comment: fantastic! Thanks ever so much for this - I just couldn't get my head round it. I think I've learnt a bit too, which is always better than just pasting a solution. So thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the old db table (source), you will not have the same (content_id, user_id) combination, then you can import using this query

```
insert newdbtable
select o.content_id, o.user_id, ifnull(max(n.`count`),-1)+1
from olddbtable o
left join newdbtable n on n.content_id=o.content_id and n.user_id=o.user_id
group by o.content_id, o.user_id;
```